# Training MSE loss larger than theoretical maximum?

Tags: python, keras, loss, sigmoid, mse

I am training a keras model whose last layer is a single `sigmoid` unit:

```
output = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
```

I am training this model with some training data in which the expected output is always a number between 0.0 and 1.0.
I am compiling the model with mean-squared-error:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Since both the expected output and the real output are single floats between 0 and 1, I was expecting a loss between 0 and 1 as well, but when I start the training I get a loss of `3.3932`, larger than 1.

Am I missing something?

**Edit:**
I am adding an example to show the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fBBrgW-HlBYhG-BUARjTXn3SpWqrHHPK/view?usp=sharing
(I cannot just paste the code because I need to attach the training data)

After running `python stackoverflow.py`, the summary of the model will be shown, as well as the training process.
I also print the minimum and maximum values of y_true each step to verify that they are within the [0, 1] range.
There is no need to wait for the training to finish, you will see that the loss during the first few epochs is much larger than 1.

Comment: This is indeed strange. Can you share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Because I tried with some dummy data and I do get MSE between 0 & 1.

Comment: Can there be a bug in the code that "ensures" real and predicted values are  between 0 and 1?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added an MCVE (see Edit). A priori the real values are between 0 and 1 (I print them) and the predicted values come from a sigmoid function, if I understand the code.

Comment: Sharing pickled data is unsafe as it's arbitrary python code being executed. Or I don't know enough to  rule that out. https://davidhamann.de/2020/04/05/exploiting-python-pickle/ . Can you share  the data in a safer format like .csv?

Comment: @oooliverrr were you able to find an answer? Did you maybe post a bug report on GitHub? It could be a bug in Keras.

Answer (score 1):

First, we can demystify `mse` loss - it's a normal callable function in `tf.keras`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

mse = tf.keras.losses.mse
print(mse([1] * 3, [0] * 3))  # tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Next, as the name "mean squared error" implies, it's a mean, meaning size of vectors passed to it do not change the value as long as the mean is the same:

`print(mse([1] * 10, [0] * 10))  # tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)`

In order for the `mse` to exceed 1, average error must exceed 1:

```
print( mse(np.random.random((100,)), np.random.random((100,))) )  # tf.Tensor(0.14863832582680103, shape=(), dtype=float64)
print( mse( 10 * np.random.random((100,)), np.random.random((100,))) )  # tf.Tensor(30.51209646429651, shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

Lastly, sigmoid indeed guarantees that output is between 0 and 1:

```
sigmoid = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid
signal = 10 * np.random.random((100,))

output = sigmoid(signal)
print(f"Raw: {np.mean(signal):.2f}; Sigmoid: {np.mean(output):.2f}" )  # Raw: 5.35; Sigmoid: 0.92
```

What this implies is that in your code, mean of `y_true` is NOT between 0 and 1.

You can verify this with `np.mean(y_true)`.

Comment: Thank you @ikamen. I have spent one too many hours testing everything that came to mind, including the possibility of `y_true`NOT being between 0 and 1. But as you can verify in my MCVE (see Edit), I print the min and max values of y_true and they do lie within the propper range.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an answer for the question asked. I am getting nans in my MSE loss, with input in range [0,1] and sigmoid at output. So I thought the question is relevant.

Here are a few observations about sigmoid:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x=tf.constant([-20, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 20], dtype = tf.float32)
x=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(x)
x.numpy()

# array([2.0611537e-09, 2.6894143e-01, 5.0000000e-01, 7.3105860e-01,
#   1.0000000e+00], dtype=float32)

x=tf.constant([float('nan')]*5, dtype = tf.float32)
x=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(x)
x.numpy()

# array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=float32)

x=tf.constant([np.inf]*5, dtype = tf.float32)
x=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(x)
x.numpy()

# array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)
```

So, it is possible to get nans out of sigmoid. Just in case someone (me, in near future) has this doubt (again).